# Why does this circuit work and the other doesn't?

Tags: electric-circuits, home-experiment

[image]

if we connect the set up like this the bulb glows but if we connect the [right wire] to the [earth of the left] then the bulb [doesn't glow].

Why does that happen?

Comment: Why does it work in the first place?

Comment: This might be better suited for electrical engineering Stack Exchange (although I do think it is on-topic here).

Comment: We can't tell what anything in that picture means.  There is no physics question here.

Comment: Please delete the question.I can't do that!

Comment: I don't even know what I'm looking at.

Comment: @kyle read the answer you will understand it better!

Comment: @govind: I should not have to read an answer to understand a question. Suppose there were no answer, what would you say or try then?

Comment: I am sorry.I will try to ask better questions.You may delete the question.I don't have that functionality right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **if we connect the set up like this the bulb glows**

If the pin positions in the photo are

```
       Ground

  Neutral   Line
```

And you are in a country where

- the neutral is linked to ground at the main panel
- but where protective devices such as GFCI or RCD are not used.

Then you have a path for current to flow from Line via Ground to Neutral.

> **if we connect the [right wire] to the [earth of the left] then the bulb [doesn't glow].**

Connecting to the ground of the left socket instead of the ground of the right socket should produce the same result if the socket is wired correctly.

The fact that it doesn't light the lamp suggests either that you made an error in your improvised unsafe connection (the connectors inside those sockets are designed for use with solid metal pins with a specific range of dimensions, not for poking stranded wire into) or that

- your socket is badly designed, badly manufactured, badly installed or is damaged. The two ground connectors are not properly connected together internally.

---

To verify this you could carry out a ground loop impedance test using a suitable Category-II test instrument (isolate the circuit line conductor first using circuit breakers or equivalent at main panel).

Comment: I tried that with standard pins it worked.thank you for answering!